Text content updated in PSD (ag-psd) layer object but image remains unchanged
I'm working on a project where I need to update text content in a PSD file programmatically using the ag-psd library in Node.js. I'm able to successfully update the text content in the PSD layer object, but when I save the modified PSD file, the image remains unchanged.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
import * as fs from 'fs';
import 'ag-psd/initialize-canvas.js';
import { readPsd, writePsdBuffer } from 'ag-psd';

const buffer = fs.readFileSync('UK DL FRONT.psd');
const psd = readPsd(buffer);

const kumonLayer = psd.children[4].children.find(layer => layer.name === 'KUMON');

if (kumonLayer) {
    kumonLayer.text.text = 'MD. Asif';
    console.log('Updated text content:', kumonLayer.text.text);
    console.log('Updated layer:', kumonLayer.name);

    const modifiedBuffer = writePsdBuffer(psd);
    fs.writeFileSync('modified_UK_DL_FRONT.psd', modifiedBuffer);
    console.log('Text for KUMON layer updated successfully.');
} else {
    console.log('Layer with name "KUMON" not found.');
}

Expected behavior:
I expect that when I update the text content of the PSD layer object and save the modified PSD file, the image in the PSD file should also reflect the changes made to the text content.
Actual behavior:
After running the above code, the text content in the PSD layer object (kumonLayer.text.text) is updated successfully, but when I open the modified PSD file, the image remains unchanged. It seems like the changes made to the layer object are not reflected in the saved PSD file.

see "Updating text layers" section at https://github.com/Agamnentzar/ag-psd .. maybe you need to open it in photoshop to "force Photoshop to redraw text layers from text data"
